# Jetty fails to serve files from Servlet 3 META-INF/resources JARs?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jetty-9

I am using [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/) from my front-end dependencies and serving them from Jetty 9.3.2. Spring MVC is used to map the resources.

The issue normally surfaces about a day after code deployment. Resource files will either return 404 or a 500 with stack like:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/webjars/angular-ui-select/0.13.1/select.js] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:156)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.lastModified(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:240)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
...
```

According to the sources and memory dump, this exception is thrown iff `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.Context.getResource(String)` returned null for a resource that was previously found.

I highly suspect this is a bug in jetty as the file that it fails to serve changes over time as well.

I have checked the changelogs and can't see anything about this.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Edit:

I traced the possible code paths against a heap dump and it seems the only possible cause is `JarFileResource.exists()` incorrectly returning false. However, apart from a potential thread-safety issue with that method, I can't find anything wrong with it either. Btrace of the method shows it returned correctly in all cases, even though the above exception were being thrown during the trace.

There's a potential issue with `JarURLConnection`'s cache feature. However, I have never seen any "file closed exception" that would indicate this bug. (The `JarFileResource` class hierarchy is btrace'd and all the caught exceptions are the expected `FileNotFoundException`s caused by Jetty searching the resources in each JAR.)

Comment: and the very first exception is?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If you are referring to the 404, it returns no stack of course. Just a plain server mesage (in an HTML 404 page): `Problem accessing /webjars/angular-ui-select/0.13.1/select.js. Reason:
  Not Found`

Comment: how have you mapped the requests for webjars in ResourceHandlerRegistry. post the relevant part

Comment: Is this using Jetty Distribution? or embedded Jetty?

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan All mappings are correct. The failures are intermittent. The same file could be served with 200 a few seconds before, then 404, then 500 then 200 again. If you read the source of the Spring class in the stack above, you'd see it's a Jetty class literally saying a file in one of the jars does not exist, which causes Spring to throw. If it's a read 404, Spring will not throw anything.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I am using the ["jetty-runner"](https://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/runner.html) artifact to launch a war from command line.

Comment: It's important to know that Jetty unpacks all jars containing `META-INF/resources` to the webapp's tempDirectory (using system temp if undeclared by you).  It is unable to serve those files directly from the jar file (as that would essentially be attempting to serve content from doubly-nested compressed archives) - if you have a system temp (aka `/tmp`) that is swept clean periodically, then you should investigate assigning a proper long-term temp directory for your webapp.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt The case you described does not apply here as Spring has its own resource handler (`ResourceHttpRequestHandler`) that directly copies the input stream from a `JarFileResource` to the client. No further unpacking of JAR files (apart form the initial WAR file) is required this way.